# What, if anything, is the difference between Micro USB and Micro B?

Tags: usb

What, if anything, is the difference between Micro USB and Micro B?

This pic shows a cable USB-A one end (ignore that USB-A end), and Micro B on the other end
[image]

And this pics shows Micro USB  (I suppose it's specifically a Micro USB B. - Micro USB A is perhaps rare.. Forget Micro USB A for now)

[image]

So what's the difference between Micro USB B, and Micro B?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any. "Micro-USB type B" and "USB micro-B" are two ways people call the same thing. Indeed even [USB-IF official documents](https://web.archive.org/web/20150427001335/http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/CabConn20.pdf) use both names for the same plug.

According to this [press release](https://web.archive.org/web/20070108050844/http://www.usb.org/press/pressroom/2007_01_04_usbif.pdf):

> **The Micro-USB specification** supports the USB On-The-Go (OTG) supplement, which was created in response to the growing need for portable devices to communicate directly with each other when a PC is not available. Micro-series definitions include: Micro-B receptacles for standard devices, Micro-AB receptacles for OTG devices, **Micro-A and Micro-B plugs**, and standard cables.

Answer (score 0):

USB connectors come in different sizes and types. Not all size and type combinations are valid, and only a few of them are used in majority of applications.

USB is asymmetrical: there's a host (originally a computer) and a peripheral device (flash drive, mouse, mobile phone etc.) The original type A/type B dichotomy reflects this asymmetry: type A was intended for hosts and type B for peripherals. Full-size type A is the most common, large rectangular connector with a horizontal plastic tab taking half of the slot. Full-size type B is the square-ish connector with two truncated corners, nowadays used mostly to connect printers.

Then there's the mini size, which was created to be used in devices too thin to fit a full-size connector. Mini type B was used for some time, superseded by even smaller micro type B which is still very common in mobile phones and various devices that charge from USB. Mini type A exists, but is practically unheard of. There's also mini type AB and micro type AB, but I've never seen one of these.

Most recently, the type C connector was introduced. Its original form factor is small enough to replace micro type B. It's also reversible, which is awesome. Type C can be used both for hosts and peripherals.

So the most common USB types are:

- USB type A - usually called simply "USB"
- USB type B - "that printer cable"
- Micro USB type B - "micro USB"
- USB type C

"Micro B" on the image you've posted is just an unofficial, shorter way of writing "micro USB type B". "Micro-USB" is the same thing.